# Difference between GCP HTTPS LoadBalancer access logs and istio logs

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, istio

I have several GKE clusters to which I have manually deployed `istio` (manually, as opposed to the managed `istio` offered by Google Cloud in GKE)

I recently received an email from Google notifying me that

> Google Cloud Platform will change the default behavior of HTTP(S) Load Balancing such that logging is no longer enabled by default.

Since my GKE clusters create HTTPS LBs for `istio-ingressgateway` resources, is whether there is any kind of logging pertaining to HTTPS LBs that I cannot see in `istio` logs?

Comment: Hi, Istio logs consist mainly of envoy logs (within mesh) and the change does not affect them. The HTTPS LB logs would be in GKE metrics explorer by default.

Comment: Will I be getting access logs if I choose to disable HTTPS LB logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `istio` access logs will be visible for each connection request that reaches Your ingress gateway.

The [HTTP(S) loadbalancer logs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#what_is_logged) are different and consist of:

> #### What is logged
>
> HTTP(S) Load Balancing log entries contain information useful for monitoring and debugging your HTTP(S) traffic. Log entries contain the following types of information:
>
> - General information shown in most GCP logs, such as severity, project ID, project number, timestamp, and so on.
> - [HttpRequest](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#HttpRequest)  log fields. However,  `HttpRequest.protocol`  and  `HttpRequest.latency`  are not populated for HTTP(S) Load Balancing Cloud Logging logs.
> - a  `statusDetails`  field inside the  `structPayload`. This field holds a string that explains why the load balancer returned the HTTP status that it did. The tables below contain further explanations of these log strings.

When You disable HTTP(S) LB logs the istio will still log all traffic that reaches istio ingress gateway and those logs will be accessible in envoy logs.

However logs related to traffic terminated at the LoadBalancer level that never reaches istio ingress gateway might not be logged.

So for example a request that did not match any of Your backends and that got terminated on loadbalancer might not leave a log behind.

If You wish to have more logs and be sure that nothing slips by, You should keep HTTP(S) LB logs enabled. Otherwise disabling these logs would reduce the amount of logs, including overlapping redundant logs with istio logs.

For more information about HTTP(S) LB visit Google cloud documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring).

For more information about Istio Logs visit Istio documentation [page](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/).

For information about GKE istio addon visit Google cloud documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview).

Hope it helps.